# Defining variables in a loop based on a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, pydicom

I am converting DICOMs to PNGs with Python 3.x and Pydicom. There are occasional errors when reading DICOM header tags, causing the script to crash. Until now, I worked around it by using exceptions like below:

```
try: studyd = ds.StudyDate
except: studyd = ''
pass
...
```

This repetitive approach lengthens the code.

Unfortunately, I fail optimizing the code by defining a dictionary containing the Pydicom header and the target variable and looping through it. How could I do this with something like:

```
ds = pydicom.dcmread()
tags = { 'StudyDate': 'studyd', 'Modality': 'modal', 'PatientName': 'patname', etc.}
for key, val in tags.items():
...
```

Comment: Do you really need to define variables like that? Can't you use a dictionary to store the values instead?

Comment: I would prefer a dictionary. Would like to make a loop that sets the "val" of my dictionary as variable name and the ds.DICOMTAG as its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ds = pydicom.dcmread()
tags = { 'StudyDate': 'studyd', 'Modality': 'modal', 'PatientName': 'patname', etc.}
header_dict = dict()
for key, val in tags.items():
    header_dict[val] = getattr(ds, key)
print(header_dict)
```

Using the `getattr` to get the header value and storing it in a dict against the specified name

Comment: Great, this did the job!
Is it OK to write the dictionary back with: "globals().update(header_dict)"

Comment: Yes you can do that. But it's usually bad practice to create variables (specially global ones) dynamically like that. You'll also confuse your IDE since it won't know where those variables came from

Comment: Could you recommend a better way to establish the variables from the dictionary?

Comment: You could just use the dictionary entry in place of the variable. Like `header_dict['studyd']`

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot.